# Criar um objeto pessoa como array dentro de um outro objeto

Tags: javascript, array, objetos

Fala Dev's! Tudo tranquilo?

Olha, me desculpem se já existe este tópico...eu procurei entre os similares e ainda assim não consegui elaborar minha resposta...

A ajuda é um pouco noob, mas será de grande valia <3

Este é o código:

```html
/*BASE DE DADOS*/
var pessoas = {
    pessoa: {
        nome: "Lucas",
        idade: "28",
        localidade: "Cruzeiro - SP",
        email: "email@email.com"
    },
    pessoa: {
        nome: "José",
        idade: "45",
        localidade: "Manaus - AM",
        email: "email@email.com"
    },
    pessoa: {
        nome: "Marcos",
        idade: "31",
        localidade: "Babuê - MT",
        email: "email@email.com"
    }
}

/*FUNÇÃO QUE IRÁ VERIFICAR SE O CONTEÚDO DO INPUT É IGUAL A UM DOS NOMES NA BASE*/
function encontre(){
    var nomecoletado = "Lucas";

    for(pessoa in pessoas){
        switch(nomecoletado == pessoas.pessoa.nome){
            case "Lucas":
                alert('Eu encontrei este nome: ' + pessoas.pessoa.nome);
                break;
            case "José":
                alert('Eu encontrei este nome: ' + pessoas.pessoa.nome);
                break;
            case "Marcos":
                alert('Eu encontrei este nome: ' + pessoas.pessoa.nome);
                break;
            default:
                alert('Não encontrei nada...');
        }
    }
}
```

O que quero é que seja mostrado o alerta de acordo com o nome coletado. Mas não consigo acessar corretamente na base de dados. O que gera como resposta toda a vez que chamo a função é que o nome encontrado é MARCOS, o último nome da base de dados. Gostaria de saber se consigo fazer isto que estou querendo. Estou estudando JS, então não quero nenhum framework ou algo do tipo, apenas JS puro.

Agradeço desde já galerinha! TMJ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro a sintaxe literal do objecto `pessoas` **(`var obj = {chave1:valor,chave2:valor, ...}` e as chaves devem ser diferentes)**  está errada,  ela contem mesma chave para valores diferentes; logo, só vai reconhecer o último elemento.

```
pessoas = {pessoa:{
email: "email@email.com"
idade: "31"
localidade: "Babuê - MT"
nome: "Marcos"}}
```

O objecto `pessoas` entra dentro do `for` só com este elemento, por isso sempre devolve o coitado do MARCOS.

O teu array de objectos deve estar assim:

```
var pessoas = [{
    nome: "Lucas",
    idade: "28",
    localidade: "Cruzeiro - SP",
    email: "email@email.com"
  },
  {
    nome: "José",
    idade: "45",
    localidade: "Manaus - AM",
    email: "email@email.com"
  },
  {
    nome: "Marcos",
    idade: "31",
    localidade: "Babuê - MT",
    email: "email@email.com"
  }
]
```

E o metódo que melhor pode te ajudar é o `find`, pois o [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

> O método `find ()` retorna o valor do primeiro elemento na matriz que satisfaz a função de teste fornecida. Caso contrário, `undefined` é retornado.

Enquanto que o A instrução `switch`

> avalia uma expressão, correspondendo o valor da expressão a uma
>   cláusula case e executa instruções associadas a esse caso, bem como
>   instruções em casos que seguem o caso correspondente.

Desta forma, usando o `find` ficaria assim:

```js
/*BASE DE DADOS*/
const pessoas = [{
    nome: "Lucas",
    idade: "28",
    localidade: "Cruzeiro - SP",
    email: "email@email.com"
  },
  {
    nome: "José",
    idade: "45",
    localidade: "Manaus - AM",
    email: "email@email.com"
  },
  {
    nome: "Marcos",
    idade: "31",
    localidade: "Babuê - MT",
    email: "email@email.com"
  }
]

/*FUNÇÃO QUE IRÁ VERIFICAR SE O CONTEÚDO DO INPUT É IGUAL A UM DOS NOMES NA BASE*/
function encontre(nomecoletado) {
  let found = pessoas.find(pessoa => {
    return (pessoa.nome.toLowerCase()).replace(/\s/g, '') === (nomecoletado.toLowerCase()).replace(/\s/g, ''); // Passar os nomes para minúsculos e remove espaços em branco, isso melhor o match
  })

  if (found) {
    alert('Eu encontrei este nome: ' + found.nome);
  } else {
    alert('Não encontrei nada...');
  }
}

function onclickBtn() {
  encontre(document.getElementById("nomePessoa").value);
}
```

```html
<h2>Encontre a pessoa:</h2>

Nome da pessoa:<br>
<input type="text" id="nomePessoa" name="firstname" value="">
<br>
<br>
<br>

<button onclick="onclickBtn()">Buscar a pessoa</button>
```

Comment: MARAVILHOSO!!!!!! Muito obrigado Cristiano, solucionou 100% a minha pergunta!! Testei e deu certinho!!

Só uma dúvida, eu tive de mudar o código dentro da função porque no seu exemplo, a função recebe um valor quando chamada e eu não sei como enviar o id de um input quando estiver chamando a função por onclick. É possível?

Ao demais, tô muito satisfeito, a explicação foi ótima! Obrigado!

Comment: @LucasNeves vou editar a resposta para incluir o função

Answer (score 0):

1) Creio que o switch não seja o adequado para resolver sua situação pois ele espera um objeto/valor único para comparar com os `cases` e no seu você está passando uma expressão (`nomecoletado == pessoas.pessoa.nome`) que pode retornar *true* ou *false* e ao comparar o resultado dessa expressão com os casos o JS acaba se confundindo. Sugiro que depure o código no navegador para experiência;
2) Em resposta à questão em si, talvez o `filter`te ajude:

```
// var pessoas = [ /* etc */ ]; // [] e não {}
var pessoas = [
    {
        nome: "Lucas",
        idade: "28",
        localidade: "Cruzeiro - SP",
        email: "email@email.com"
    },
    {
        nome: "José",
        idade: "45",
        localidade: "Manaus - AM",
        email: "email@email.com"
    },
    {
        nome: "Marcos",
        idade: "31",
        localidade: "Babuê - MT",
        email: "email@email.com"
    }
];
let selecao = pessoas.filter(p => p.nome.toLowerCase() == nomecoletado.toLowerCase())[0];
```

O filter vai te retornar um array, por isso o `[0]` no fim para obter o primeiro elemento. Faça alguns testes e prepare o código para a possibilidade de filter retornar `null` ou `undefined` também.

Comment: Show! Vou testar aqui e posto o resultado jajá!

Comment: Editei para incluir o array corretamente.

Comment: Gustavo, infelizmente não gerou nenhum resultado.

Comment: Estranho... o mesmo é executado aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/GustavoAdolfo/1gpst2cr/1/    Faça as comparações para averiguar.